# Is there a Python package that generates SOA data structure from AOS?

Tags: python, numpy, oop

I was working on increasing the performance of existing Python applications lately. What I found is that arranging data in arrays of basic data types (as a struct of arrays) instead of an array of structs/classes can increase performance. If data is saved in contiguous memory it also makes outsourcing heavy calculations to the GPU easier. My goal is to provide our users with a way to make use of SOA without having to know about numpy, numba, simd, etc.

Intel provides a template library and containers that can generate simd friendly data layouts from a struct/class.

https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/libraries/introduction-to-the-simd-data-layout-templates.html

This already gives an idea how something similar could be done in Python.

So, instead of reading objects from memory (that can be distributed somewhere in memory),

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

a_s = [A(1) for _ in range(10)]

for a in a_s:
    a.x=2
```

I would like to have the data accessible as numpy array AND as instance of class A. So, that data can be accessed something like this:

```
sdlt_container = generate_SDLT(A(), 10)
a = sdlt_container[2]  # returns instance of class A 
a.x = 2                # returns a view to second element in numpy array and sets x[2]=2
sdlt_container.x[0:5] = 3  # Change x in several "instances of A"
```

Accessing data as an instance of class A might involve creating a new instance of A but the variables in this object should "point to" the correct index in the numpy array. I understand that optimizations like the Intel compiler does in a for loop are not possible in Python (interpreted vs compiled).

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: The best idea I've seen in past SO was to maintain the primary data in the array form, and have the objects contain indices (or wbat ever) needed to access their own values from the arrays. But I don't recall any detailed implentation for a specjfic case, much less a general tool.

Comment: don't be surprised if this gets closed as  disallowed 'recommendation' question.